# How do I disable the scrollbar in the original PDF viewer on Android?

Tags: android-10, pdf, huawei-p20

I have an Android 10 Huawei P20. I have not installed any PDF reader apps.

I want to disable the scrollbar on the side when I'm reading PDFs. It's way too easy to accidentally hit and end up hundreds of pages off from where I was at, meanwhile not having nearly enough precision to actually be remotely useful.

I've been googling it for awhile, but every resource I find just screenshots stuff that looks nothing like the viewer my phone came with by default. Mine doesn't have any settings options as far as I can tell. It gives me a back button to close the file, following by the title of the file I have open, followed by a search option, a share option, and the three vertical buttons which open into options to send the file, download it (even if I opened it from my download folder), print it or send feedback to Google. I also can't find it in my apps list or any mention of pdfs in the settings options for my phone.

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat as my PDF reader on Android and I don't have this issue, so I may consider using it. (Disclaimer: I work for Adobe.)

Comment: You may use something like - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.readera&hl=en_IN&gl=US. You can go page by page instead of vertical scrolling.

Comment: I consider this a direct competent answer